# ajax asp.net not working after deploy to azure web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I set the AjaxControlToolkit Copy local to true. I also uninstalled and reinstalled it.I also checked Remove additional files while publishing. all my ajax tools have no responed after i publish it to azure web app.

any ideas? help!!

by the way the ajax version is 15.1 and i am runing visual studio 2015 .netframwork 4.6

Comment: Did you look in Azure to see if your DLL's were published?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set Copy to local property to true for the dll you have in the bin directory. So this file will be pushed when you deploy to Azure.